# Change of port number not workingin sprintboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I changed default port number from 8080 to 8082 in application.properties file using server.port=8082. Even after changing port number, if I try to run sprint boot app, server is taking default port 8080 and application is not starting.
Error message;
Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

Answer (score 1):

i solved it like this

Solution

1. Enter 'server.port='8080' (changed port number) in the following 'application.properties' file where you can create a project.
2. After connecting to the terminal

Type 'sudo lsof -i :[port number you want to check]' to see which ports are running.
Delete server.port and run it again.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To address this aspect,

> configure this application to listen on another port

can be achieved in Spring Boot by instructing the application to start on a random available port **each time it runs**.

This proves particularly beneficial when aiming to prevent port conflicts, especially in scenarios where multiple instances of the application are executed concurrently.

To implement this, open your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file and include the following line:

```
server.port=0
```

Setting the `server.port` property to 0 directs Spring Boot to select a random available port during the application's startup.